# When using MVVM, how do I extend the ViewModel in child ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I have a hierarchy of this sort:

```
class OneViewModel {
}

class OneViewController {
  var viewModel = OneViewModel()
}

class TwoViewModel : OneViewModel {
}

class TwoViewController : OneViewController {
  var viewModel = TwoViewModel() // ???
}
```

I know that overriding property types is not allowed in Swift, but it doesn't make sense for the child ViewController to carry two ViewModels, how would one go about solving this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this:

```
class OneViewController {
  var viewModel: OneViewModel {
    return storedViewModel
  }
  lazy var storedViewModel: OneViewModel = {
    type(of: self).viewModelProvider()
  }()
  class func viewModelProvider() -> OneViewModel {
    return OneViewModel()
  }
}

class TwoViewController {
  override var viewModel: TwoViewModel {
    return storedViewModel as! TwoViewModel
  }
  override class func viewModelProvider() -> OneViewModel {
    return TwoViewModel()
  }
}
```

It's somewhat verbose to setup, but is easy and clear to use afterwards.

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
class OneViewModel {
}

class OneViewController {
    var viewModel = OneViewModel()
}

class TwoViewModel : OneViewModel {
}

class TwoViewController : OneViewController {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.viewModel = TwoViewModel()
    }
}
```

you can set your `viewModel` instance to be `TwoViewModel` class anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I figured so.. My only quirk with this solution is that it would require casting the view model from OneViewModel to TwoViewModel every time you access it in TwoViewController. I hope this can be avoided somehow.